# symfony add select option in materialize reload jquery

Tags: jquery, symfony, materialize

Hi I use Materialize css and symfony ,
 when i render  a choicesType element

```
<div class="row" id="indirizzo_row">
       <div class="input-field col s12">
           {{ form_widget(form.idIndirizzo) }}
            <label for="textarea" class="">Indirizzo</label>
       </div>
```

the html result is :

```
<div class="row" id="indirizzo_row">
   <div class="input-field col s12">
       <div class="select-wrapper initialized"><span class="caret">▼</span>
            <input type="text" class="select-dropdown" readonly="true" data activates="select-options-404a0618-34d9-457a-953e-d80885817d6c" value="Value1">
            <ul id="select-options-404a0618-34d9-457a-953e-d80885817d6c" class="dropdown-content select-dropdown ">
                      <li class=""><span>Value1</span></li>
              </ul>
            <select id="appbundle_select_id" name="appbundle[idIndirizzo]" class="initialized">
                <option value="1221">Value,1</option></select>
       </div>
    <label for="textarea" class="">Indirizzo</label>
    </div>
 </div>
```

and the select is in display:none

My goal is in jquery reload field and add or remove a option select value

I try this:

```
          $("#indirizzo_row").load(location.href+" #indirizzo_row>*","");
          (this add a option in select but not in ul li list 
          $("#indirizzo_row").material_select();
```

but it don't work

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#indirizzo_row select").material_select();
```

or

```
$("#appbundle_select_id").material_select();
```

Try test. 
You need to use the Select element.

Answer (score 0):

I understand my wrong

```
$("#select_id").material_select();
```

work before than

```
$("#select_id").load(location.href+" #select_id>*","");  finish.
```

so i resolve with

```
  $("#select_id").load(location.href+" #select_id>*",function(){

                    $('select').material_select();
              });
```